# Grails - unit testing with using JSON request does not work

Tags: json, grails, testing

I have the following controller code:

```
@Transactional
def save(MyModel model) {
    model.save()
}
```

I'm testing it using:

```
request.json = new MyModel(property1: 1, property2: 2)
controller.save()
```

However, every time I run the test, I get `NullPointerException`, because `model` is null. Do I need to put any other code to get the binding to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the test code working, I called `controller.request.json` instead of just `request.json`. In addition, based on [dmahapatro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24037415/404604), I set the the method to `POST`.

Here's how the working code looks like:

```
controller.request.method = 'POST'
controller.request.json = new MyModel(property1: 1, property2: 2)
controller.save()
```

#### Update

While the controller method `save` does not get null object anymore, the properties that the JSON data are supposed to set are not set.

#### Update 2

After *starting a different project* and doing mostly the same thing, everything worked even binding properties to method argument.

Answer (score 7):

Setting domain object to `request.json` should work if the domain object is mocked appropriately in controller unit spec/test.

Instead, you can also set a JSON string to `request.json` in the test, which will then be bound to `MyModel` when controller action in called. So your test should look like:

```
request.json = '{"property1": 1, "property2": 2}'
```

Also note, since you do not have an `id` in the request payload, which indicates you are trying to POST a new record. In this case, the data binding with the domain object will only work if the http method is set to `POST` in the request explicitly.

```
request.method = 'POST'
```

Comment: In the code above, I was following the official testing documentation of Grails, which also mentioned that it's possible to use JSON string instead. I tried using that but it still won't work. I've just tested setting `request.method` to `POST` like you suggested, but the model is still null. I'm using Grails 2.3.9.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have to make myself up to date with the docs. Can you add your full test class and controller action and corresponding url mapping? Also make sure you use `@Mock` for MyModel in test.

Comment: I've just run another test now using `controller.request.json` instead of just `request.json` and it worked. Now the problem I'm having is when I set a UUID string in the JSON string, I get a `JSONException`.

Comment: I must have had no coffee this morning. I meant `controller.request.json` but just copied your question, it should work that way as well. Add the tests.